# In a Phoenix Framework form, how can I set a belongs_to relation back to null using a changeset?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

In a Phoenix Framework form, I have a select box on my page which has an option to set a belongs_to value to nil.

```
<%= select f, :relation_id, 
  Enum.into(Enum.map(@relations, fn p -> {p.name, p.id} end), 
  [{"None", nil}]) %>
```

The form would usually send the ID, but when the nil value is selected, it passes the value as an empty string:

```
"relation_id" => ""
```

I receive an error from Ecto that the changeset is invalid, as it expects an integer.  I could probably intercept the map, set the value to null, and pass the updated map into the changeset.  But is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: How do you preload the `relations` field in your controller? Can't find an example on how to do it with a changeset. Thanks

Comment: Ahh - the select just expects a basic list of tuples and can be generated however you like.  In this case, @relations was just a straight pull using Repo.all:   relations = Repo.all(relations_query), and then passed into the view in the render command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should use the plug [scrub params](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#scrub_params/2).

Try to add to your controller:

```
defmodule MyApp.SomeThingController do
  use MyApp.Web, :controller

  plug :scrub_params, "some_thing" when action in [:create, :update]

  # def ....
end
```

It will be convert `""` (empty) values to `nil` values.

Hope it helps.